# How to redirect https .php file to https nice url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've looked and can't seem to find the answer to this.

How to I redirect in htaccess:

```
https://www.example.com/html/my_application.php
```

to...

```
https://www.example.com/my-application/
```

It seems so simple yet I can't can't get it to redirect to the nice url. I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^html/my_application.php https://www.example.com/my-application [R=301]
```

Comment: Did you add `RewriteEngine on`? Are you meaning that you want to visit `/my-application/` and have it display the other URL quietly in the background? If so you have it the wrong way round and I will add an answer to clear that up. Let me know.

Comment: Yep, I have lots of rewrites, just can't get this one to work. I want the url with my_application.php to redirect to the nice url  /my-application/ but stay https. Make sense?

Comment: So you want it so that when people visit /html/my_application.php, they get redirected to /my-application/? With a 301 so the URL in the address bar changes.

Comment: Yes and still be HTTPS. I can't seem to get it to work with https. It worked when did it with just HTTP. I must be missing something.

Comment: Well you just need to make sure it's being used on the site that is serving your HTTPS site. Nothing more to it than that.

Comment: In the htaccess file I have RewriteRule ^html/my_application.php https://www.example.com/my-application [R=301,L] on a development subdomian with no HTTPS, it redirects fine. On my HTTPS subdomain it does not redirect like I think it should, just goes to https://www.example.com/html/car_loan_application.php

Comment: Well you don't have the `https://` part in the RewriteRule? Also how does car_loan_application come in to it? That's not what we're looking at redirecting here.

Comment: Sorry, supposed to be my-application. I have this in the htaccess file, https://www.example.com/html/my_application.php https://www.example.com/my-application [R=301,L] and it does not redirect to the nice url. I tried with just ^html/my-application.php too.